# How to reconstruct 3d meshes from 2d images of a scene?

Tags: graphics3d, mesh, machine-learning, textures, computer-vision

The new `ImageStitch` was nice functionality added in v13, but is there anything available for constructing meshes (with color textures) from a bag of 2D images (taken at different angles/positions)?

[image]

You can reconstruct surfaces (with as little as 10-20ish photos) easily on some mobile apps like [widar](https://widar.io/en/top/), and many python implementations exist for this problem that are efficient, most prominently [NGP from Nvidia](https://nvlabs.github.io/instant-ngp/).

I would like to know, ***what has been done on this topic for wolfram language?***

To get started, here are a few simple test sets containing 10s of jpegs showing an object at different angles with uniform backgrounds: https://github.com/AlansCodeLog/photogrammetry-test-sets

Here's the code to get the first one, which is 33 images of a rock:

```
URLDownload["https://gitlab.com/photogrammetry-test-sets/dice-turntable-strong-lights-heavily-textured-w-watercolors/-/archive/master/dice-turntable-strong-lights-heavily-textured-w-watercolors-master.zip","~/Downloads/"]
files=ExtractArchive[%, $TemporaryDirectory];
images=Import /@ %
```

[image]

**References:**

Recently many paid sites and apps can build radience fields for you from bags of 2D images and videos. See widar, lumalabs.ai, and many others.

Here are some links to the research on Photogrammetry and a few relevant tools:

- COLMAP is a general-purpose Structure-from-Motion (SfM) and Multi-View Stereo (MVS) pipeline with a graphical and command-line interface: https://colmap.github.io/tutorial.html
- Original paper/repo on the first method capable of photo-realistically reconstructing a non-rigidly deforming scene using photos/videos captured casually from mobile phones using neural radiance fields (NeRF): https://nerfies.github.io/
- Nice video about photogrammetry with examples for archeology: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1KJNCOJAULw
- Repos with useable code:

  - https://github.com/google/mipnerf
  - https://github.com/kwea123/ngp_pl
  - https://github.com/gaochen315/DynamicNeRF

Comment: This technique is typically called photogrammetry, to help you in your search.

Comment: @CarlLange I know but didn't want to scare people away with that word ;). I've achieved this in Python 3.9 on an ec2 p3x4 instance with custum cuda extensions... but frankly this is beyond Wolram for the moment.

Comment: You're better off using Agisoft Metashape - photogrammetry, not radiance fields based. For radiance fields, there's also Plenoxels which is non-neural and much faster than NeRF. I think Plenoxels might be the most promising as spherical harmonics are easy to represent in Mathematica, but you'll still need camera estimation. It's a huge amount of work though e.g regular photogrammetry: `ImageKeypoints` for all cameras, filtering, matching, depth/matrix estimation from epipolar lines, RANSAC/bundle adjustment, then finally dense point cloud and marching cubes for a mesh.